# Is there the way to add an extra custom code before jump instruction while using MS Detours?

Tags: c++, winapi, detours

As known, MS Detours library copies a few set of starting instructions of the hooked function to the trampoline, and places the jump instruction to hook function. I need to add some extra custom code before this jump. Is there a legal documented way to do this?

Comment: at first no, at second you really not need this

Comment: How would that even work? What makes you think there's room for those extra instructions? Put those extra instructions at the target of the JMP, since that's dynamically allocated. JMP doesn't change any register or flag other than EIP of course.